# How to exclude categories from WordPress blog post page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm using a static page for my front page and another page for my blog post.

How can i exclude certain categories from showing up on my blog page.  I've seen the code for the front page but can't get it to work for my blog page

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-10,-12,-13' );
}
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_posts' );

function exclude_category_posts( $query ) {
if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
$query->set( 'cat', '-359, -2' );
    }
}
```

Try this by putting in your functions.php

Comment: I tried this in my AccessPress Magazine theme.  It didn't work.   my site is  www.treyofivetv.com  

My blog is TOF LATEST on the menu (www.treyofivetv.com/blog)

I copy/paste the code in the function.php file (added my 'cat').  Nothing happened. The categories still showed up in the blog.

Comment: HEYYYYYY.  I got it to work.  THANKS :)  I had a couple of spaces in places where they shouldn't have been.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange your code should have worked try this way.

```
function exclude_category($query)
{
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query())
    {
        //Alternative method
        $query->set('category__not_in', array(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this in my AccessPress Magazine theme.  It didn't work.   my site is  www.treyofivetv.com  

My blog is TOF LATEST on the menu (www.treyofivetv.com/blog)

I copy/paste the code in the function.php file (added my 'cat').  Nothing happened. The categories still showed up in the blog.

Comment: I got the above code to work.  Thanks for your help. i did use the array but with the "-" sign in front of the id's.    Thank You